# How to submit an InfoPath-built form to a Library With a Dynamic URL?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-library

Salvete!  I have a custom infopath-built form.  I also have 100 subsites - children of a single site collection.  I plan to deploy my forms library via powershell to each site, and then, since I used a content type, if I want to edit the questions, the changes will go out to all 100 sites.

Now, I don't want users to have to tell where to save the form.  When the user clicks the save button, I want Sharepoint to save the form in a library named "Reports" on whatever site they happen to be.  The url is standard:
http://myportal.mydomain.com/subsite1/reports
or
http://myportal.mydomain.com/subsite2/reports
http://myportal.mydomain.com/subsite3/reports

You get the idea.  Now, how do I tell it to submit the form and save it to that dynamic location?  I only want to configure the infopath content-type template.

I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29547/infopath-2010-form-library-unique-file-names), but the poor fellow never got any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the idea is to generate a url that you want to use as the destination of your submit action, take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/11/08/submitting-to-this-document-library.aspx) which has some code to do the job that you can attach to a button you have placed on the form using infopath.  In your submit options, it has you place a "dummy url" that the code will replace with your dynamically built url.

I don't think you can do this without using custom code.

Look at [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49067/how-to-submit-an-infopath-built-form-to-a-library-with-a-dynamic-url/49385#49385) and [this thread, too](https://ashrafhossain.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/publishing-administrator-approved-infopath-form-template-with-custom-code/), about submitting to the form's own library for some details about getting custom code to work.  There isn't much difference between using the form's own library than building a dynamic URL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following step-by-step article should answer most of your doubts and questions:

- [Jo-Anne Alfafara. Side-by Side versioning with Content Types](http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/jo-anne_alfafara/archive/2010/10/06/side-by-side-versioning-with-content-types2.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure you read my question; that page does not tell me anything at all about dynamic urls.  Perhaps you could recommend some bit of a snippet of something I could use within InfoPath's "submit options > Perform custom action using code" feature.